# How to conditionally fill column with previous values "rowwisely" with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, data-wrangling

I am aiming to replace values from a column with previous values conditionally on other columns. Those values can but need not be missing. I am checking a variable `check` against a threshold and when the `check` is above such `th` I am calling it a match. Whenever there is a match, I would like to replace the `value` with its own previous observation. **The only catch is that when there are sequential matches, I would like to carry the first value forward (downward) and not only replace with its own lag.** The data set barely fits my memory, so working with `data.table` is preferred.

Concretely, say I have the following data

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

dt <- data.table(tribble(
    ~id, ~check, ~value, 
    1,       .1,     10,
    2,       .6,     20,
    3,       .7,     50,
    4,       .5,     NA,
    5,       .1,     90,
    6,       .7,     NA,
))
```

and conduct the following checks

```r
th <- .5
dt[, ck_match := if_else(condition = check > th,
                         true = "matches_above",
                         false = "no_match")][]

#>    id check value      ck_match
#> 1:  1   0.1    10      no_match
#> 2:  2   0.6    20 matches_above
#> 3:  3   0.7    50 matches_above
#> 4:  4   0.5    NA      no_match
#> 5:  5   0.1    90      no_match
#> 6:  6   0.7    NA matches_above
```

This is closely to what I am aiming, but with the issue that in `row 3` I was aiming to *carry the value forward* from `id==1` until the first `no_match` and not taking always the value from `lag(value)`.

```r
dt[, ck_shift := if_else(condition = check > th,
                         true = shift(
                         false = value)][]
#>    id check value      ck_match ck_shift
#> 1:  1   0.1    10      no_match       10
#> 2:  2   0.6    20 matches_above       10
#> 3:  3   0.7    50 matches_above       20
#> 4:  4   0.5    NA      no_match       NA
#> 5:  5   0.1    90      no_match       90
#> 6:  6   0.7    NA matches_above       90
```

To be very clear, what I aim is:

```
# id check value
# 1    0.1    10
# 2    0.6    10
# 3    0.7    10
# 4    0.5    NA
# 5    0.1    90
# 6    0.7    90
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I don't understand where id:4 receives its value. This could be quite easy if that's just a typo. Make a new column for value, set it to NA if the threshhold is met, then use nafll with last observation carried forward ("locf").

`dt[, val2 := value]`
`dt[check > th, val2 := NA]`
`dt[, nafill(val2, type = "locf")]`

Comment: value of id:4 is just missing. No underlying reason.

Comment: It's missing in the tibble, but not in your example output. There it has the value 70, which isn't a value anywhere in the input.

Comment: Oh. now I see. Fixed that. Your solution is very close to what I am aiming at, but it also replaces the missing from id:4, resulting in `value:10 10 10 10 90 90` when it should be `value:10 10 10 NA 90 90`. I believe I can adapt from that and get to what I am aiming though. Thank you for your time and attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got one solution.

1. `grp` is the group ID generated by `rleid(ck_match`)
2. `last` is a varible storing the last value of previous group

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

dt <- data.table(tribble(
    ~id, ~check, ~value, 
    1,       .1,     10,
    2,       .6,     20,
    3,       .7,     50,
    4,       .5,     NA,
    5,       .1,     90,
    6,       .7,     NA,
))
th <- .5
dt[, ck_match := fifelse(check > th,
                         "matches_above",
                         "no_match")]
dt[, grp := rleid(ck_match)]
this <- NA_real_
dt[, value := {last <- this; this <- last(value); last; fifelse(check <= th, value, last)},
   by = grp]
dt[,`:=`(ck_match = NULL, grp = NULL)][]
#>    id check value
#> 1:  1   0.1    10
#> 2:  2   0.6    10
#> 3:  3   0.7    10
#> 4:  4   0.5    NA
#> 5:  5   0.1    90
#> 6:  6   0.7    90
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>